# white space in matplotlib fill between function

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a question  regarding matplotlib `fill_between` function.

I'm trying the following:

```
y_list=[0.35328659,  0.97313739,  0.98385365, -0.97960526, 
0.98658943,  0.97615343,
          0.97539618,  0.97751352,  0.96911883,  0.96291649,  0.9493149,   0.93523555,
          0.94011452,  0.91881423,  0.90835381,  0.88725635 , 0.89163797,  0.87300867,
          0.87035654,  0.87672802,  0.85594486 , 0.88945495,  0.94530403,  0.96636498,
          0.95950467,  1.00002651 , 1.0254289 ,  1.02018627 , 1.03353243,  1.01131321] 

y=np.array(y_list)

x=range(len(y_list))

cond=(y >= 0) & (y <=1)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(30,5))

ax.fill_between(x, 0, y, where=(cond), color='C0', alpha=0.3,interpolate=True)
ax.fill_between(x, y, 1, where=(cond), color='C2', alpha=0.3,interpolate=True) 
ax.fill_between(x, 0, y, where=(y>1 ), color='C0', alpha=0.3,interpolate=True) 
ax.fill_between(x, y, 1, where=(y<0 ), color='C2', alpha=0.3,interpolate=True) 
ax.margins(x=0, y=0) 
plt.show()
```

and the result looks differently than I expected:
[image]

I do not understand where the white part arround 24 comes from.
Could anyone help or has any idea how I could achieve what I want?

Comment: `y` is less than 1 up to index 25. So the third line doesn't fill until x = 25. It will then interpolate up from 0 at x = 24, which is the diagonal line you see.

Comment: Regarding the `where` kwarg, I just want to make sure you know that it is used to limit the x range and does not do anything about the y values. So, saying `where=(y<0)` means that it should find the x values where that is satisfied and fill that region in.